# glDrawElementBaseVertex() vs glDrawElement()

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, gpu

I want to be straight forward, that's why i start with the scenario:-

suppose you want to draw two cubes and suppose you've **created,binded,filled** the buffer objects with data for both cubes, and you have the element array for both cubes as follows:

```
const GLshort indexData[] =
{
//Object 1
0, 2, 1,        3, 2, 0,
4, 5, 6,        6, 7, 4,
8, 9, 10,       11, 13, 12,
14, 16, 15,     17, 16, 14,

//Object 2
18, 20, 19,     21, 20, 18,
22, 23, 24,     24, 25, 22,
26, 27, 28,     29, 31, 30,
32, 34, 33,     35, 34, 32,
};
```

the first way to draw the two objects is as follows:-

```
// first Cube
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

// second Cube
glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData),GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, numberOfVertices / 2);
```

however is it possible to use the following code for drawing both cubes?

```
// first cube
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

//second cube
// set the indice pointer to 24 so that it starts reading data for the second cube
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pointer to 24th element);
```

and if yes, so what is the point of using `glDrawElementBaseVertex()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

In the code:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

The last element is a pointer to an array of indices. In this case you are passing 0, which is the null pointer, which means that OpenGL will take the indices from the bound array. It is not an offset.

In the second piece:

```
glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData),GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, numberOfVertices / 2);
```

The last argument is an offset, as you intended.
Also, If you plan on drawing just half of your buffer for each call, you should change the count argument from

```
ARRAY_COUNT(indexData)
```

to

```
ARRAY_COUNT(indexData)/2
```

In order to draw half of the buffer each call.

Please read the documentation on the two functions for more information:
[glDrawElements](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml)
[glDrawElementsBaseVertex](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElementsBaseVertex.xml)

Comment: my point is that if we specify a pointer to the 24th with that function suffice ??

Comment: Yes, but then opengl cant use the bound index buffer. This is how it worked before index buffers.

Comment: Of course. You can easily just pass a pointer to where you want the data to start.

Comment: so if we want to fully utilize the index buffer, for the first object we should use a basevertex of 0, and for the second one use a basevertex of 8, using the glDrawElementsBaseVertex() am i right???

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Actually, I'm reading the same online book as you are, and I encountered the same problem as you are.

I've tested your code(the one with "24th element"), and it works just like the original one:

With the original

```
glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData),
    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0, numberOfVertices / 2);
```

I got

[image]

and with

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ARRAY_COUNT(indexData), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 
    (void*)(indexData + 24));
```

I got

[image]

They are same.

In fact, I'm thinking of this problem all day.

As the book points out([here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut05%20Optimization%20Base%20Vertex.html), check the second paragraph of the last Note), (on a 32-bit OS)if you have a model containing more than 65536(2 bytes) vertices, then the element array cannot use GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT(2 bytes) as the index's type any longer. Instead, it must use GL_UNSIGNED_INT(4 bytes). It takes twice the storage.

Then check [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/) to see the Description of glDrawElementsBaseVertex. It says that if the value of (*indices*[i] + *basevertex*) exceeds the maximum of *type*, then the value will be upconverted to 32-bit unsigned int.

With those references in mind, I have the following conclusion:

For example, let's say I have a 3D character consists of 1,000,000 vertices. If I use glDrawElements to render it, I have to use GL_UNSIGNED_INT to store the indices, and that will take about 3.8MB. But, if I can use something like "65536 * *numberOfPage* + *index*"(if I can break those vertices down in different "pages", just like random-access, and use *index* to indicate vertex in that page; and 65536 may be the size of the page) with glDrawElementsBaseVertex, I can still use GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT to store those indices. And in this case, it will save me about 1.9MB.

Maybe 1.9MB doesn't sound like a big number, but think of the situation of modern 3D video game. I'm sure those characters must consist of far more than 1,000,000 vertices, and in that case, it may be 190MB instead of 1.9MB that glDrawElementsBaseVertex save for you.

Anyway, this is just my speculation, because I'm also a beginner in OpenGL and Computer Graphics. :)